# Remove/hide or update a Bootstrap panel from shinyWidget

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs, shinywidgets

In order to make an app where panels are created dynamically, I would like to remove, hide and/or update panels from the package **shinyWidgets**.

I didn't find any function to do so nor way to add IDs to these panel.

If you have the solution or a way around, I would be more than happy. Thank you in advance !

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
    panel(
      heading = "Test panel",
      actionButton("remove_panel", "Remove this panel")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    observeEvent(input$remove_panel,{
      print("remove panel")
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official method you can use to change the panel states, but we can do it with custom expressions.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    panel(
        heading = "Test panel1",
        id = "test_panel1",
        actionButton("remove_panel", "Remove this panel")
    ),
    panel(
        heading = "Test panel2",
        id = "test_panel2",
       "some content"
    ),
    actionButton("hide_panel", "Hide this panel")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    observeEvent(input$remove_panel,{
        removeUI('.panel:has([id="test_panel1"])', immediate = TRUE)
    })
    observeEvent(input$hide_panel,{
        toggle(selector = '.panel:has([id="test_panel2"])')
        if(input$hide_panel %% 2 == 1) return(updateActionButton(inputId = "hide_panel", label = "Show this panel"))
        updateActionButton(inputId = "hide_panel", label = "Hide this panel")
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

To remove:

1. add an ID argument to your panel, and use `removeUI` to remove it. Remember to change the ID in you own case.

To hide/show:

1. We can use `toggle` from `shinyjs` to show or hide some elements we choose.
2. Use `updateActionButton` to also change it text when hidden.

[image]